# How to update several lines in a MYSQL database from flutter app

Tags: android, mysql, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm here for some help. I've been trying to update several lines of a MYSQL database but I haven't been successful.

I attach the code that I am using.

```
import 'package:cedi/data/connect.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DocPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DocPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DocPage> createState() => _DocPageState();
}

class _DocPageState extends State<DocPage> {
  static List<DocsPickers> _docs = [];

  List docs = [
    {
      "qty": "400,0000",
      "date": "2023-07-24 07:43:00",
      "doc": "5275",
      "picker": "51",
      "sku": "VS100511",
      "cont": "25J2"
    },
    {
      "qty": "1152,0000",
      "date": "2023-07-24 08:04:00",
      "doc": "5275",
      "picker": "51",
      "sku": "VS100512",
      "cont": "25J2"
    }
  ];

  Future<void> _dataDocs() async {
    final db = Database();
    await db.connect();

    for (var _doc in docs) {
      final date = DateTime.parse(_doc["date"]);
      final doc = _doc["doc"];
      final sku = _doc["sku"];

      final results = await db.query(
        'UPDATE table1 SET date = ? WHERE doc = ? AND sku = ?',
        [date.toIso8601String(), doc, sku],
      );

      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('Updated rows: ${results.affectedRows}');
    }

    await db.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _dataDocs();
        },
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}

class DocsPickers {
  String? sku;
  DateTime? date;
  int? doc;
  double? qty;

  DocsPickers({required this.sku, required this.doc, this.date, this.qty});
}
```

```
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

class Database {
  late MySqlConnection _connection;

  Future<void> connect() async {
    _connection = await MySqlConnection.connect(
      ConnectionSettings(
        host: 'host',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'user',
        password: 'password',
        db: 'db',
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Results> query(String sql, List<Object> list) async {
    return _connection.query(sql);
  }

  Future<void> close() async {
    await _connection.close();
  }
}
```

**ERROR:**

Exception has occurred.

MySqlException (Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE doc = ? AND sku = ?' at line 1)

Comment: Look at the `query` function in your database class. `Future<Results> query(String sql, List<Object> list) async {
    return _connection.query(sql);
  }`. You are passing it a list as the second argument, but then you are not using that list in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'? WHERE doc = ? AND sku = ?'  this means mysql server recevived the query that you did not replace '?' to real pamaters.

you can show the code that you call "query()", the problem may be the codes that some lines before it.